# Case statement in terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

Hi I have below block of terraform code which creates for me Virtual machines for sql and app roles.

```
module "sql_vms" {
  source                = "../../modules/compute/"
  rg_name               = var.resource_group_name
  location              = module.resource_group.external_rg_location
  vnet_name             = var.virtual_network_name
  subnet_name           = var.sql_subnet_name
  app_nsg               = var.application_nsg
  vm_count              = var.count_vm
  base_hostname         = var.sql_host_basename
  sto_acc_suffix        = var.storage_account_suffix
  vm_size               = var.virtual_machine_size
  vm_publisher          = var.virtual_machine_image_publisher
  vm_offer              = var.virtual_machine_image_offer
  vm_sku                = var.virtual_machine_image_sku
  vm_img_version        = var.virtual_machine_image_version
  username              = var.username
  password              = var.password
  allowed_source_ips    = var.ip_list
}

module "app_vms" {
  source                = "../../modules/compute/"
  rg_name               = var.resource_group_name
  location              = module.resource_group.external_rg_location
  vnet_name             = var.virtual_network_name
  subnet_name           = var.sql_subnet_name
  app_nsg               = var.application_nsg
  vm_count              = var.count_vm
  base_hostname         = var.app_host_basename
  sto_acc_suffix        = var.storage_account_suffix
  vm_size               = var.virtual_machine_size
  vm_publisher          = var.virtual_machine_image_publisher
  vm_offer              = var.virtual_machine_image_offer
  vm_sku                = var.virtual_machine_image_sku
  vm_img_version        = var.virtual_machine_image_version
  username              = var.username
  password              = var.password
  allowed_source_ips    = var.ip_list
}

module "resource_group" {
  source                = "../../modules/resourcegroup/"
  rg_name               = "test_rg"
}
```

Whilst it helps me get the job done. I don't think this is ideal as there are lot of common parameters and only few which change to create a different roles

Parameters specific to roles are below:

```
subnet_name
vm_size
vm_publisher
vm_offer
vm_sku
vm_img_version
```

Possible to do in terraform a case statement or perhaps a loop?

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't solve the problem mate.I believe what you suggested is for 1 iteration which is fine. However, I have a set of list for which I have to execute terraform config. I do not wish to repeat the same blocks as I am doing here.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create multiple VMs with different parameters?

Comment: Yes mate! That is what I want, apologies if my message was not clear. To use same block where I am calling a module and pass different parameters. Rest of the parameters (or at least the majority) remain the same

Comment: I'm afraid there is no case statement in the Terraform and if you use the module, the count is also not available. You can take a look at [HashiCorp Terraform 0.12 Preview: For and For-Each](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/).

Comment: What's the status of your problem? Do you solve it as you want?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet, need to look at some for and for_each loops with map object, that might be the way to move forward.

Comment: Do you find the excepted solution? I suggest you take a try to use a list map inside the for_each or the for loop.

Comment: Do you get any solution as you want? Maybe we can take a talk to solve it.

Comment: Not sure how can we talk. But yes I am open to chat with you. I have changed the job but still, terraform is in my heart.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is not to find a loop to achieve, instead, you can try to set the default value for every variable and only input the special value for the variable which you want to specify. Just like Azure in Terraform Registry, such as the [compute](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Azure/compute/azurerm/1.3.0). There a lot of variables for the compute, but you only need to specify the variable which you want and need. I think this is the way you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Looping for modules isn't yet supported (as of terraform v0.12.26) but one thing you could do to address the repeatable common configuration is to pass in a configuration variable which contains all the common stuff. Then when inserting it into your module, merge it with a map that contains the specific elements for that particular module instance.

To use your code as an example of what I mean, it's possible to do the following:

```
locals {
  common-configuration = {
    rg_name            = var.resource_group_name
    location           = module.resource_group.external_rg_location
    vnet_name          = var.virtual_network_name
    subnet_name        = var.sql_subnet_name
    app_nsg            = var.application_nsg
    vm_count           = var.count_vm
    sto_acc_suffix     = var.storage_account_suffix
    vm_size            = var.virtual_machine_size
    vm_publisher       = var.virtual_machine_image_publisher
    vm_offer           = var.virtual_machine_image_offer
    vm_sku             = var.virtual_machine_image_sku
    vm_img_version     = var.virtual_machine_image_version
    username           = var.username
    password           = var.password
    allowed_source_ips = var.ip_list
  }
}

module "sql_vms" {
  source          = "../../modules/compute/"
  configuration   = merge(local.common-configuration, {
    base_hostname = var.sql_host_basename
  })
}

module "app_vms" {
  source          = "../../modules/compute/"
  configuration   = merge(local.common-configuration, {
    base_hostname = var.app_host_basename
  })
}
```

This then becomes much easier to read and see the module specific things that matter. You can also update all common configuration at the same time knowing you wont miss one of the modules. Within your module residing at `"../../modules/compute/"`, you'd then refer to you variables like `var.configuration.rg_name` rather than `var.rg_name`.

You could also go one step further and separate the structure of your configuration from how your modules refer to variables being passed in by having a sort-of mapping layer. This would also allow you to set defaults that don't reside within the common configuration (or indeed you could do this instead of the common configuration but I find it's easier to maintain if that config is co-located by the module using it. It also allows you to pass in outputs from other modules like you have done). An example of this would look like the following (assuming using the above as well):

```
variable configuration {}

locals {
  rg_name            = var.configuration.resource_group_name
  location           = var.configuration.external_rg_location
  vnet_name          = var.configuration.virtual_network_name
  subnet_name        = var.configuration.sql_subnet_name
  app_nsg            = var.configuration.application_nsg
  # Example of setting a default value if it doesnt exist within the configuration
  vm_count           = lookup(var.configuration, "count_vm", 2)
  sto_acc_suffix     = var.configuration.storage_account_suffix
  vm_size            = var.configuration.virtual_machine_size
  vm_publisher       = var.configuration.virtual_machine_image_publisher
  vm_offer           = var.configuration.virtual_machine_image_offer
  vm_sku             = var.configuration.virtual_machine_image_sku
  vm_img_version     = var.configuration.virtual_machine_image_version
  username           = var.configuration.username
  password           = var.configuration.password
  allowed_source_ips = var.configuration.ip_list
}
```